# How to change iPhone application Settings?

Tags: iphone, settings

I have such problem ...
In my iPhone Application I want to import settings I create a Settings.bundle and Settings appear when I go to close my application and go to the settings of iPhone I can see the settings that I import. Now I want same settings to be visible in mt application. I dont want to close my application to change settings I want to change settings in my applications !!! How I can do this ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Apple, the settings available in your application should be of a different nature to the settings you access outside of the application (accessed via Springboard's Settings page).

The distinction is as follows:

- Settings inside your application should be settings the user might want to frequently change. That's why they're inside your app, for quick access. An example: background music on/off in a game.
- Settings outside your application should be the sort of infrequently changed "preference" settings that the user might only ever configure once, or very infrequently. For example, a "Units of measurement: metres/feet" setting would be suitable for this, since a user would probably just configure it once when they first installed the app.

So, to summarise, the same settings shouldn't be replicated in both places.

But don't just trust me, [read exactly what Apple say](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/Preferences/Preferences.html).

Good advice from Apple here, I recommend you follow it.

Comment: This is Apple's advice, however it is, nevertheless, bad advice. Most users never look in the Settings app. I've lost count of the number of emails asking for features that already exist. As soon as I duplicated those settings inside the app, those emails all but dried up.

Comment: And can you tell me how can I initialize my tableview with settings boundle file ???

Comment: @Stephen Darlington Did you try placing a simple message in the in-app settings saying "Settings also available in the Springboard settings application" or similar? If it were clickable, you could offer the user some advice that told them what exactly what they could configure in the settings app. I think that's preferable to putting all the settings in the main app.

Comment: @occulus My personal preference is that the settings should be in the Settings app. However, many users never look there, even when you tell them to do so (there was a hint on the first launch screen).

Comment: @ViTo Brothers There are a number of Open Source projects that do this. The one I use is: https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit